# JdbcOdbc Error. i cant connect to the ODBC driver

Tags: java, sql, odbc

I'm currently studying this program and I've tried to solve this myself, but it seems that I can't understand what went wrong.

How can I connect it to my database? :)

Here is the my code below:

---

```
package payroll.system;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;


public class clsConnection {
        String url = "";
        String username = "";
        String password = "";


    public Connection setConnection(Connection conn, String username, String password )

    {
        try
    {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        String fileName = "MakeDB.ini";        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        props.load(in);
        String drivers = props.getProperty("jdbc.drivers");
        if(drivers != null)
        System.setProperty("jdbc.drivers", drivers);
         url = props.getProperty("jdbc.url");
         username = props.getProperty("jdbc.username");
         password = props.getProperty("jdbc.password");
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);

    }catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.err.println("SQl Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

           catch(IOException e)
           {
               System.out.println("\nIO Exception");
           }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("\nAnother Error");
            }
            return conn;

    }




}
```

THIS IS THE ERROR after I compile the program:

```
SQl Exception
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6964)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7121)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(JdbcOdbc.java:3080)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(JdbcOdbcConnection.java:323)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:174)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that you have not set up odbc driver. to set up odbc driver you need to go to `Administrative Tools` under `Control Panel` and chose appropriate driver to setup ODBC. You can visit [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca6axakh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for more details. Hope this helps.